# Did Yondu know Peter had "swapped" the orb?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

At the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy*, Peter relinquishes the orb to Yondu. Peter tells Yondu not to open it, and Yondu obliges until curiosity gets the better of him. It's then revealed that he had not been given the real orb.

I'm wondering, did Yondu know the whole time that Peter had given him a fake? He must have been pretty certain when he opened it, because he may have been risking the destruction of his ship. Is there any evidence for this in any printed adaptations of the movie?

The way he smiles when he sees that Peter gave him a new knick-knack for his console makes me wonder, and of course in Volume 2 we find that Yondu respects the authority/power of the Nova Corps and has a soft spot for Peter.

Comment: The printed adaptation of the movie doesn't go beyond the point at which Yondu and Quill agree to work together to extract the orb from the Dark Aster.

Comment: "risking the destruction of his ship" hardly. Throughout the movie people safely looked at the stone. So long as they didn't touch it's perfectly safe. He opens the orb with no one else around (the lowest risk time to do so) if the stone had been inside he could have closed it again no problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did he know? No. Did he suspect they’d been swapped? Absolutely. Peter is Yondu’s son, might not be biological but he was raised by him. Yondu would swap the orbs so he’d suspect Peter would too. Michael Rooker, Yondu’s actor, sums this up in an interview himself as well.

> **I have to ask, because the sequel is coming and we know next to nothing about it. But the movie ends with Yondu… I mean he will be back, and Kraglin will be back, and the Ravagers. But the movie ends with him being made a fool of, to a certain extent.**
>
> Rooker: No, not really. Not at all. I think what it is, as the relationship between Yondu and Peter Quill, Star-Lord, has been, even at the very end, strengthened, because, in my opinion, Yondu expected Star-Lord to mess with him again on this.
>
> Come on. Would he have really opened it if he really thought it was a bomb or some sort of crazy weapon?
>
> **I read it that way in the theater! I’m relieved that you agree that it was almost a proud smile…**
>
> Rooker: It was an absolutely proud smile. I was thrilled that he tried to do it to me, he tried to screw me over yet another time. No way. Of course. Yondu is very proud that his surrogate son has once again shown his true colors. My thought when I opened the orb and I see Peter’s trinket, I see it as, “That’s my boy. He’s done it to me again and I expected it.” I was somewhat taken back that he did it, you know?
>
> <sub>[ScreenRant, Michael Rooker Talks Yondu's Role In 'Guardians Of The Galaxy 2'](https://screenrant.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-blu-ray-michael-rooker-interview/)</sub>